# tinyMCE with Javascript

Tags: javascript, tinymce

I am attempting to insert text data at a cursor position containing other text data.  I'm using the following tinyMCE code:

**tinyMCE.activeEditor.selection.setContent("Text String");**

Instead of being inserted, it completely overwrites the existing data with just the text string passed in appearing in the buffer.  In examining the documentation, I found that this code is supposed to replace, not insert text at a cursor location. Whoever originally coded this was mistaken in its' use.

My question:  Is there a different piece of code that will allow insertion, not replacement of text data into a data buffer?

Answer (score 1):

You want the `insertcontent` API:

https://www.tinymce.com/docs/api/tinymce/tinymce.editor/#insertcontent

For example:

```
tinymce.activeEditor.insertContent("<p>This is new</p>");
```